# CANopen Stack to read data from a Hyper9 motor

Tags: stm32, canopen

I am trying to get the RPM data from the hyper 9 motor . Hyper 9 is interfaced to STM32 . So I have a basic question. Do I need CANopen Stack on STM32 side to read the data or will I be able to receive data just by using CAN receive driver .

Comment: You do need high level library

Comment: Do you mean something like CANopenNode ?